# didgits between 1 and 1000 that sum up to 3

Tags: math

I am trying to find out the numbers between 1 and 1,000 that the sum of their digits is equal to 3. I am just looking for any formula that can help me calculate this. For e.g. 111, or 12 equals to 3, the ones, tens, and hundreds added up together will equal 3.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Always try from your end and post your code if you are struck some where. we are always here to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think of all numbers having 3 digits:  `001` and `002`

We can start to iterate on this quickly.  You *cannot* have a number in that sequence greater than 3.

So immediately we rule out all numbers >= `400`

We can also rule out,within each group of hundred, any number that is greater than `?40` (eg `140` `340`)

Then we can start to just press into the numbers a bit.

We only have to dig into `?01` - `?39` for 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Start with `00?`.  We know that there is only one number works here : `0 + 0 + x =3` solve : `003`

So we have 0, moving up to the next set of 10 : `01?` we know there is only one number that will work.  `012`.

We have logic, each leading two digit combination leads to only one solution.  We know we only have `0??` `1??` `2??` and `3??` for the leading digit.  We have `?0?` `?1?` `?2?` and `?3?` for the second digit.

We can be comfortable listing : 3, 12, 21, 30, 102, 111, 120, x13?, 201, 210, x22?, 300

If you don't want to use math, use python:

```
a=[]
for x in range(10):
  for y in range(10):
    for z in range(10):
      if x+y+z==3:
        a.append('%r%r%r'%(x,y,z))

a = ['003','012','021','030','102','111','120','201','210','300]
```

Comment: 201 is another digit that I don't see here

Comment: @cool yeah i typed the answer for python must have missed that, it does come out in the script above